# For loop not working to extract data from the multiple files in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to make the following loop to work. I can get the output which I want if I run it on the commandline with one file as input but it's not extracting with the for loop.  Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(/home/dd/ff/*.txt)
for file in $FILES
do
    grep -r -i -A4 'Compliance Calculation'  "$file"

 done
```

Comment: Missed the #2 below. But why not do `grep -r -i -A4 'Compliance Calculation' /home/dd/ff/*.txt` ? Good luck. –

Comment: @shellter theoretically this could expand to a value greater than ARG_MAX

Comment: agreed, but I'm not sure that for `for file in $FILES` could deal with that situation either. We're getting little feedback on the requirements, so I'm onto other things ;-) Your #3 is the best solution. Good luck to all.

Comment: Also grep will output file names when you run it on many files, so you'd want to add a `-h` option.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=(/home/dd/ff/*.txt)
for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
   grep -r -i -A4 'Compliance Calculation' "$file"
done
```

See [my video](http://youtu.be/yTijxqjZhRo) on bash variable expansion for an explanation.

Comment: This answer is highly bash specific and should be avoided in portable code.

Comment: @GoodPerson the question asks about bash

Comment: true, but the code does not need to be bash specific. Since this code can be easily written in a portable manner, using bashisms should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal fix is to get rid of `FILES` altogether.

```
for file in /home/dd/ff/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this script:

1. Avoid using bash specific features.  Instead use /bin/sh not /bin/bash. If you must use bash then /usr/bin/env bash.  Directly invoking /bin/bash is not portable.
2. $() runs a command, it does not expand a glob. It will attempt to run whatever file earliest in the expansion as en executable.
3. you should be using the find |xargs pattern instead of a for loop.  Try find /home/dd/ff/ -maxdepth 1-name '*.txt' |  xargs grep -hr -i -A4 'Compliance Calculation'
4. If you must use a loop you can just expand the glob directly in the loop:

   for file in /home/dd/ff/*.txt

Comment: #1 depends on which shell you want to use, and #3 has problems of its own (as written) that a `for` loop does not.

Comment: Good catch with #2 but disagree with #1 and concede with @chepner.

Comment: @chepner nope; if you want to use bash you should be using /usr/bin/env bash.  /bin/bash is almost always wrong

Comment: That's an issue with which path to `bash` is required, not which shell itself is used to run the script. `/bin/sh` is absolutely wrong if the script uses `bash`-only features.

Comment: @chepner I've updated the answer to more specifically explain why I gave #1.  I never intended to use bash specific features with /bin/sh. I meant instead to avoid bashisms in portable code.

Comment: The OP has indicated they are using `bash`; telling them to use `/bin/sh` is not helpful in any meaningful way in the context of the question. The only problem with the code is an apparent confusion over how to build a list of file names and how to iterate over it. #1 is irrelevant; #2 does not suggest a fix; and #3 breaks on file names which contain spaces, which the original code (ignoring the already recognized problem with building the list of file names) does not.

Comment: #1 is general code improvement; #2 is addressed in #3/4; #3: good point.  I added an alternate in #4.